# Passing Parameters through stored Procedure

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am new to interfacing DB's with applications and am trying to pull a couple of fields from a database where the parameter I specified should filter out the results. I keep receiving a no parameters or arguments were supplied. Can anyone shed a little insight on this? Thanks.

below is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC dbo.PassParamUserID

AS
set nocount on
DECLARE @UserID int;

SELECT f_Name, l_Name
FROM tb_User
WHERE tb_User.ID = @UserID;
```

And here is my code

```
class StoredProcedureDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StoredProcedureDemo spd = new StoredProcedureDemo();

        //run a simple stored procedure that takes a parameter
        spd.RunStoredProcParams();
    }

    public void RunStoredProcParams()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        string ID = "2";

        Console.WriteLine("\n the customer full name is:");

        try
        {
            //create a new connection object
            conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\UserDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True; Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();

            //create command objects identifying the stored procedure
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PassParamUserID", conn);

            //Set the command object so it know to execute the stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //ADD PARAMETERS TO COMMAND WHICH WILL BE PASSED TO STORED PROCEDURE
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", 2));

            //execute the command
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //iterate through results, printing each to console
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First Name: {0,25} Last Name: {0,20}", rdr["f_Name"], rdr["l_Name"]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your SQL stored proc to:

```
ALTER PROC dbo.PassParamUserID

@UserID int

AS set nocount on

SELECT f_Name, l_Name FROM tb_User WHERE tb_User.ID = @UserID;
```

At the moment you are just declaring it as a variable within the procedure.

Here are some MSDN articles that may help you going forward:

[Creating and Altering Stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

[Declaring Local Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258839%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Does this mean I user the DECLARE @UserID when I create the S_Proc and then change it to @UserID when it goes to Alter?

Comment: No, you define the parameters before the AS statements for both creating and altering procedures. I've added links to some MSDN articles in my answer.

Comment: @japlov. `Declare` defines a local variable in the same way  `string ID = "2";` did. The `ALTER PROC dbo.PassParamUserID @UserID int` made it a Parameter the same way `RunStoredProcParams(string ID)` would. The Alter was because you needed a change and for no other reason

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROC dbo.PassParamUserID (@UserID int)

AS 
set nocount on 
SELECT f_Name, l_Name FROM tb_User WHERE tb_User.ID = @UserID;
```

If you want to pass a parameter in you need to define it before the AS statement as  shown above.